# How do I change the formatting of numbers on an axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R and ggplot to draw a scatterplot of some data, all is fine except that the numbers on the y-axis are coming out with computer style exponent formatting, i.e. 4e+05, 5e+05, etc. This is unacceptable to me, so I want to get it to display them as 500,000, 400,000, and so on. Getting a proper exponent notation would also be acceptable.

The code for the plot is as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(valids, aes(x=Test, y=Values)) +
  geom_point(position="jitter") +
  facet_grid(. ~ Facet) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Fluorescent intensity/arbitrary units") +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Test repeat") +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=median, fun.ymax=median, fun.y=median, geom="crossbar")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Be careful of describing `ggplot` default options as "obviously unacceptable". You mean you have a *personal preference* for a different format. A number in the format `4e+05` is scientific notation, and would be the preferred formatting in a wide variety of applications.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I also found another way of doing this that gives proper 'x10(superscript)5' notation on the axes. I'm posting it here in the hope it might be useful to some. I got the code from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/a_xhMoQyxZ4) so I claim no credit for it, that rightly goes to Brian Diggs.

```
fancy_scientific <- function(l) {
     # turn in to character string in scientific notation
     l <- format(l, scientific = TRUE)
     # quote the part before the exponent to keep all the digits
     l <- gsub("^(.*)e", "'\\1'e", l)
     # turn the 'e+' into plotmath format
     l <- gsub("e", "%*%10^", l)
     # return this as an expression
     parse(text=l)
}
```

Which you can then use as

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
   geom_point() +
   scale_y_continuous(labels=fancy_scientific)
```

Comment: If you don't want 0 to be printed as "0 x 10⁺⁰", add the following below the `format(...)` line:
`l <- gsub("0e\\+00","0",l)`

Comment: If you want to special case other things, it's easiest to add more `gsub()` directly after the `format()`, while testing what `format()` returns for your case in a separate console.

Comment: add this before last `gsub` command:
`# remove + after exponent, if exists. E.g.: (3x10^+2 -> 3x10^2)`
  `l <- gsub("e\\+","e",l)`
and after it:
`# convert 1x10^ or 1.000x10^ -> 10^`
  `l <- gsub("\\'1[\\.0]*\\'\\%\\*\\%", "", l)` to make it in format usually used in papers.

Comment: Asked a followup question to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477686/how-do-i-make-ggplot2-custom-text-formats-from-axis-scale-functions-follow-forma

Answer (score 168):

Another option is to format your axis tick labels with commas is by using the package `scales`, and add

```
 scale_y_continuous(name="Fluorescent intensity/arbitrary units", labels = comma)
```

to your ggplot statement.

If you don't want to load the package, use:

```
scale_y_continuous(name="Fluorescent intensity/arbitrary units", labels = scales::comma)
```

Comment: Amazing that such a trivial issue requires to load a new package.

Comment: FYI, this also works with scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma), and I'm assuming other scales in ggplot2.  Great tips!

Comment: Very late to this, but you can pass any function to the labels argument so `scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ","))`

Answer (score 47):

```
x <- rnorm(10) * 100000
y <- seq(0, 1, length = 10)
p <- qplot(x, y)
library(scales)
p + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error that formatter is an unused argument? Does it need another package or something?

Comment: I changed the code to include `library(scales)` and use `comma` which should work better than the function that I had before.

Answer (score 18):

I'm late to the game here but in-case others want an easy solution, I created a set of functions which can be called like:

```
 ggplot + scale_x_continuous(labels = human_gbp)
```

which give you human readable numbers for x or y axes (or any number in general really).

You can find the functions here: [Github Repo](https://github.com/1R151-1/R/blob/master/ggplot2_formatter.r)
Just copy the functions in to your script so you can call them.

Answer (score 12):

I find Jack Aidley's suggested answer a useful one.

I wanted to throw out another option. Suppose you have a series with many small numbers, and you want to ensure the axis labels write out the full decimal point (e.g. 5e-05 -> 0.0005), then:

```
NotFancy <- function(l) {
 l <- format(l, scientific = FALSE)
 parse(text=l)
}

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:100, 
                         y = seq(from=0.00005,to = 0.0000000000001,length.out=100) + runif(n=100,-0.0000005,0.0000005)), 
       aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_point() +
     scale_y_continuous(labels=NotFancy)
```

Comment: This can be shortened by using an anonymous function: `scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})`
Why there is no pre-defined formatter like that, hell knows.

Comment: @eMPee584 Sorry for bumping this old reply but please consider making this an answer, so it can be found more easily :) Your comment has more upvotes than some of the actual answers.