# How to fix the unit values in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot and my data looks like this:

```
diversity position
113 2098776
116 4598777
67 5626222
200 6423068
...
```

and I used this script:

```
qplot(position, diversity, data = FILE)
```

but when plot appears, in  x axis I see values like 0e+00 1e+07 , but i want to convert these values begin from 0 to 60 instead..
any guide please?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could rescale the data,

```
qplot(scales::rescale(position, c(0,60)), diversity, data = FILE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you load the scales package `library(scales)` and then Try this `qplot(position, diversity, data = yourdataframe) + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)`

Comment: now units got realy huge like 10,000,000 40,000,000  how can I make it smaller?

Comment: This would really be reproducing the answer of @Jack Aidley, as mentioned by @Gopala`qplot(position, diversity, data = yourdataframe) + scale_x_continuous(labels=fancy_scientific)`. Please note that `fancy_scientific` is the name of a function used to format labels on x-axis. You can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot)

Comment: Another possibility is `qplot(position, diversity, data = yourdataframe) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))`