# Clear labeling of times class data on horizontal barplot/geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Background: I need to display the time each hospital bed is emptied (via patient discharge) and the time a new patient is placed in the bed, with markers indicating steps taken in between to prepare the bed for the new patient.

Plotting goals: My intention is to have two horizontal bars for each Room/Bed: one (currently in grey) showing the patient who's been discharged, and another (in blue) showing the new patient who's been placed in the same bed.

Question: How can I better display time on the x-axis?
I'd be grateful for any referrals to documentation on working with class = "times" data, too.

Sample data:

```
BedMap <- structure(list(
  Date = structure(c(17210, 17210, 17210, 17210, 17210, 17210, 17210), class = "Date"), 
  RoomBed = c("TestBed1", "TestBed2", "TestBed3", "TestBed4", "TestBed5", "TestBed6", "TestBed7"), 
  UnitGroup = c("Tele", "Tele", "2P", "2P", "3P", "Tele", "ICU"), 
  DcOrderTime = structure(c(0.358333333333333, 0.377777777777778, 0.430555555555556, 0.470833333333333, 0.395833333333333, 0.623611111111111, 0.441666666666667), 
                      format = "h:m:s", class = "times"), 
  DcTime = structure(c(0.457638888888889, 0.475694444444444, 0.5, 0.59375, 0.625, 0.700694444444444, 0.770833333333333), 
                 format = "h:m:s", class = "times"), 
  DecisionTime = structure(c(0.582638888888889, 0.539583333333333, 0.886111111111111, 0.596527777777778, 0.675, 0.653472222222222, 0.777777777777778), 
                       format = "h:m:s", class = "times"), 
  RequestBedTime = structure(c(0.60625, 0.545138888888889, 0.91875, 0.84375, 0.707638888888889, 0.713888888888889, 0.857638888888889), 
                         format = "h:m:s", class = "times"),
  DepartTime = structure(c(0.629166666666667, 0.599305555555556, 0.974305555555556, 0.952083333333333, 0.859722222222222, 0.770138888888889, 0.910416666666667), 
                     format = "h:m:s", class = "times")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
  .Names = c("Date", "RoomBed", "UnitGroup", "DcOrderTime", "DcTime", "DecisionTime", "RequestBedTime", "DepartTime"))
```

And current plot, with times displayed as decimals:

[image]

```
ggplot(BedMap) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, #start of light grey bar, indicates bed occupied & discharge planning has not yet started
               y = RoomBed, 
               xend = DcOrderTime, #end of light grey bar
               yend = RoomBed), 
           color = "Light Grey", 
           size = 6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = DcOrderTime, #start of dark grey bar, indicates bed still occupied but discharge planning has begun
               y = RoomBed, 
               xend = DcTime, #end of dark grey bar, indicates patient has been discharged, bed is unoccupied
               yend = RoomBed), 
               color = "Dark Grey", 
               size = 6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = DepartTime, #start of blue bar, indicates new patient has been placed in bed
               y = RoomBed, 
               xend = 1, #end of blue bar (set at midnight/end of day)
               yend = RoomBed), 
               color = "Blue", 
               size = 6) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DecisionTime, 
             y = RoomBed), 
         color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = RequestBedTime, 
             y = RoomBed), 
         color = "green", size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Room-Bed", title = "Daily Bed Map")
```

When I view the BedMap df, the times show up formatted correctly (eg. DcOrderTime shows up as "08:36:00", "09:04:00", "10:20:00", "11:18:00", "09:30:00", etc.). But the x-axis is displayed as a decimal. Is there a way to just tell my plot code to display the x-axis as "times" class, without having to map the decimals to  display values?

```
View(BedMap)
```

Comment: What are your time values? How would you like to display them? Write a function that converts the time values into the format you want, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot for the way to use it.

Comment: When I use View(BedMap) for the current data, as above, the time values show up as times, eg.: DcOrderTime <- c("08:36:00", "09:04:00", "10:20:00", "11:18:00", "09:30:00", "14:58:00", "10:36:00"). I know how to map a random label on top of an axis, but I figured since the data is already in times format, I shouldn't have to do any conversion. I thought there might be a way to just specify that the axis should be displayed in h:m:s format.

Comment: Where is the `times` class defined?

Comment: Kent, I think this is my problem! It's from the chron package. I've used it in the past because it's easier to perform calculations on time data. But in this case perhaps I need to start fresh and redefine my times as POSIXlt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, I think, linked to the fact that the `times` class appears to be holding durations rather than times of day (though I cannot actually find the documentation on the class, having never used it before). Because that format is not explicitly handled by `ggplot` it is being converted to `numeric` for plotting (you can see the stored numeric values in your output from `dput`).

While there is likely a better solution involving converting to `POSIX` or storing the values directly as time of day, you can accomplish your immediate goal by simply multiplying the `numeric` value (which is fraction of a day) by 24 to get the time. Then, set sensible axis breaks and add labels as desired, like so:

```
ggplot(BedMap) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, #start of light grey bar, indicates bed occupied & discharge planning has not yet started
                   y = RoomBed, 
                   xend = 24*DcOrderTime, #end of light grey bar
                   yend = RoomBed), 
               color = "Light Grey", 
               size = 6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 24*DcOrderTime, #start of dark grey bar, indicates bed still occupied but discharge planning has begun
                   y = RoomBed, 
                   xend = 24*DcTime, #end of dark grey bar, indicates patient has been discharged, bed is unoccupied
                   yend = RoomBed), 
               color = "Dark Grey", 
               size = 6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 24*DepartTime, #start of blue bar, indicates new patient has been placed in bed
                   y = RoomBed, 
                   xend = 24, #end of blue bar (set at midnight/end of day)
                   yend = RoomBed), 
               color = "Blue", 
               size = 6) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 24*DecisionTime, 
                 y = RoomBed), 
             color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 24*RequestBedTime, 
                 y = RoomBed), 
             color = "green", size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Room-Bed", title = "Daily Bed Map") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 24, 3)
                     , labels = sprintf("%02d:00",seq(0, 24, 3))
                     )
```

Which gives

[image]

The builtin in `scale_x_time` does not appear to work here, and that is part of what leads me to suspsect that the `times` class holds durations rather than times of day. If you are using this format often, it may be worthwhile to instead write your own transformation/scale function to use repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Turns out the answer lies in the fact that class="times" is from the chron package. By adding a simple line at the end of my plot, the display changed simply, without additional mapping. See my original code below, plus additional last line.

```
ggplot(BedMap) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, #start of light grey bar, indicates bed occupied & discharge planning has not yet started
           y = RoomBed, 
           xend = DcOrderTime, #end of light grey bar
           yend = RoomBed), 
       color = "Light Grey", size = 6) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = DcOrderTime, #start of dark grey bar, indicates bed still occupied but discharge planning has begun
           y = RoomBed, 
           xend = DcTime, #end of dark grey bar, indicates patient has been discharged, bed is unoccupied
           yend = RoomBed), 
           color = "Dark Grey", size = 6) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = DepartTime, #start of blue bar, indicates new patient has been placed in bed
           y = RoomBed, 
           xend = 1, #end of blue bar (set at midnight/end of day)
           yend = RoomBed), 
           color = "Blue", size = 6) +
    geom_point(aes(x = DecisionTime, 
         y = RoomBed), 
     color = "black", size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = RequestBedTime, 
         y = RoomBed), 
     color = "green", size = 3) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(x = "Time", y = "Room-Bed", title = "Daily Bed Map") +
    scale_x_chron(format = "%H:%m", n = 12)
```