# avoid scientific notation x axis ggplot

Tags: r

This:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Bla), bins = 30, labels = TRUE, format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
    geom_histogram()
```

does not work. I want to suppress the scientific notation (e.g. 1.0e+07). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How about a working example?

Comment: You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610377/how-do-i-change-the-formatting-of-numbers-on-an-axis-with-ggplot#11611825
The idea being that you can use the `scales` package to reformat the labels of your axes.

Comment: You can use `options(scipen = 999)` before you plot

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK it does the trick - if ok please post answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `options(scipen = 999)` before you plot.

This will disable scientific notation in general and not only in your x-axis.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of options apart from `options(scipen = 999)` which you may want to avoid if you don't want set this for all charts.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Bla), bins = 30) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ format(.x, scientific = FALSE))
```

or

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Bla), bins = 30) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Instead of `scales::comma`, the `scales` packages also offers

- scales::label_number()
- scales::label_dollar()
- scales::label_date()

which are handy if you have financial data or dates.